# Django urls.py regex doesn't match?

Tags: regex, django, url, python-2.7

[image: Snapshot]

I'm pretty sure my regex is correct, but somehow it cannot capture the parameter and complaining no page found/match... I'm really stuck, if anyone can help me anything...heap thanks

This is the related part of my urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import *
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from api.views.forgot_password import password_reset

url(r'^reset_password/(?P<auth>\w+)/(?P<email>\w+)/$', password_reset),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(?P<email>\w+)` part is incorrect. `\w` match only digits, `_`, alphabets (not `@`, `.`).

Use following url:

```
`^reset_password/(?P<auth>\w+)/(?P<email>[^/]+)/$`
```

This does not strictly match email. But that will not be issue because you should check email with User.email.

Comment: Ok, I understand now... the regex is wrong after all lol...
Heap thanks for mentioning that...I'll accept your answer happily:)

Comment: @Romans8.38-39, Some email could contain `%`, `+`, `-`, ...; I updated the url again.

Comment: yes, you're right... I'm not really good at regex :( 
Many thanks falsetru:)